# How would I use selenium's headless mode in python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-chrome-headless

I am using the same code that's in the recent patch notes and it's still not working.

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

My code works without headless mode, otherwise, I get this error:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

I also tried this and it didn't work:

```
service = Service(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

selenium 4.18.0
Python 3.10.7

Comment: Can you share the entire error traceback? When does the error raise, while creating the browser or while browsing the web?

Answer (score 0):

The cumbersome settings of Selenium and its web drivers is one of the reasons why I created [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) as an extension to Selenium. [Headless mode simply works out of the box with Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/user-guide/performance/headless/#how-to-configure).

In full disclosure, I'm the author of this package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

Maybe something like this could solve your problem?

```py
from browserist import Browser, BrowserSettings

settings = BrowserSettings(headless = True)

with Browser(settings) as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://example.com")
```

[Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) has a mature set of methods to interact with web pages, but if you prefer working with the Selenium web driver, you can also return to the standard `driver` and continue your script with this:

```py
    driver = browser.driver
```

Note that simple settings of headless mode of [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) work across browser types, so you can even do something like this if you already have Chrome, Edge, Firefox installed:

```py
from browserist import Browser, BrowserSettings, BrowserType

chrome = BrowserSettings(type = BrowserType.CHROME, headless = True)
edge = BrowserSettings(type = BrowserType.EDGE, headless = True)
firefox = BrowserSettings(type = BrowserType.FIREFOX, headless = True)

for settings in [chrome, edge, firefox]:
    with Browser(settings) as browser:
        browser.open.url("https://example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

With [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), activating Chrome's new headless mode (`"--headless=new"`) is just:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(headless2=True)
```

A regular script could look like this:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
driver.open("seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
driver.highlight("h2")
driver.type("#myTextInput", "Automation")
driver.click("#checkBox1")
driver.highlight("img", loops=6)
driver.quit()
```

Or if you prefer using a context manager so that the browser always closes at the end:

```py
from seleniumbase import DriverContext

with DriverContext() as driver:
    driver.open("seleniumbase.github.io/demo_page")
    driver.highlight("h2")
    driver.type("#myTextInput", "Automation")
    driver.click("#checkBox1")
    driver.highlight("img", loops=6)
```

If needed, there are a lot more [SeleniumBase syntax formats](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md) to choose from.